# No "suspend" option upon pressing power button

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and I'd like to suspend the machine by pressing the power button and then clicking on "suspend" on the opened dialog, like I've been doing for about 9 years.

Now the options I am given are just: Lock Screen, Cancel, PowerOff.

How can I add it again?

Comment: [related](/questions/762268/change-power-button-action-comand-for-hibernate-option-in-gnome-3-18)